# For every continuous function $g$ does there exists a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ which converges to $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

Let, 
$C(\Bbb R):=\\
\{f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R| \text{ $f$ is continuous and $\exists$ a compact set $K$ such that $f(x)=0$, $\forall x\in K^c$}\}.$
Let, $\displaystyle g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. 
Then prove that there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C(\Bbb R)$ such that $f_n \to g$ uniformly.

Here $g$ is continuous, so by Weierstress approximation theorem we can say that there always exists a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x)\}$ in $K$ which converges uniformly to $g$ in $K$. But in that case how can I define $f_n(x)$ in such a way that $f_n \in C(\Bbb R)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ tends to $0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ you can just take $f_n = g\phi_n$
where $\phi_n$ is a smooth (for your questions continuous is sufficient) cutoff function such

$\phi_n(x)=1$ on $[-n,n]$, $\phi_n(x)=0$ on $(-\infty,-n-1]\cup[n+1,\infty)$, and $0\le \phi_n(x) \le 1$ elsewhere.

Comment: Your $\phi_n$ is not well defined ! In $[-n-1,n+1]$, $\phi_n=0$, so how it $=1$ in $[-n,n]$ ?

Comment: @Empty thanks for pointing that out, I was obviously not focused when I wrote this. The fix should be obvious though -- fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} g(x), & |x| \le n \\
g(n)(n+1-|x|), & n<|x| \le n+1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$ (I am using the fact that $g$ is even, but it is clear how this would work for any $g$ that satisfies $g(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to\infty$.

Then $\|g-f_n\|_\infty \le \sup_{|x| \ge n} g(x) = g(n)$, hence the convergence is uniform since $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x) = 0$.

Comment: I think $f_n(x)$ is NOT continuous at $x=-n$. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to (-n)^- }f_n(x)=(2n+1)g(-n)=(2n+1)g(n)$. But, $f_n(-n)=g(-n)=g(n)$.

Comment: Are you looking for answers or looking for flaws? The idea is straightforward. Run with it and figure out the answer yourself, this is not a paid answering service, this is people trying to help you solve well known problems and are spending their free time TRYING TO HELP PEOPLE. $g$ is even for Christ's sake.

Comment: Wow. I am hoping there were some deleted comments that justified my irate response at the time.

Comment: No. Actually no comment has deleted !!